# Laravel Validation Login form validation fails in Password confimation?

Tags: php, forms, validation, laravel, laravel-validation

I have two forms, login and signup forms, and one User model, i have set-up my rules and messages in User class, which are static members, $rules and $messages, the problem i face now, is in sign up form everything validate the it should be, but in login form, after i put a correct email and password, it gives me "Password confirmation doesn't match" which it shouldn't because there is no password_confrimation field in the login form.

Rules and Messages in UserModel

```
public static $rules = [
    'email' => 'required|email',
    'password' => 'sometimes|required|confirmed',
    'password_confirmation' => 'sometimes|required'
    ];

public static $messages = [
    'email.required' => 'The email is required',
    'email.email' => 'the email attribute is not in a email format',
    'password.required' => 'the password is required'
];
```

Login action

```
    $validateUser = Validator::make($inputs, User::$rules, User::$messages);

    $user = new User();
    $user->email = $inputs['email'];
    $user->password = $inputs['password'];
```

Comment: Maybe it's better to define separate validation rules for login and signup? I keep signup rules in my User model, and login rules in my SessionsController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did like this in my project

```
public static $rules = array(
                        'email'      => 'required|email|unique:users,email',
                        'password'   => 'required|min:6',
                        'repassword' => 'same:password',
                        'group'      => 'exists:groups,id',
                        'last_name'  => 'required',
                        'first_name' => 'required',
                       );
```

Give it a try .

Comment: it gives me another validation error **The password confirmation does not match.
The password confirmation field is required when password is present.**